# How to use contexual filters for registration events?

Tags: views

I want to create a block on the side of the page that will show registered users to a event. I already have a event type and calendar system + a registration system.

When a user registers for a event, I can get the view to display it. However, it is displaying literally ALL registration users for ALL events. I am trying to get the contextual filter to just narrow it down to the specific event, but cannot get it to work.

Any help?

Comment: Provide a default in your contextual filter. Otherwise it shows all content if no value is available. What module are you using to do the reference between user and event?

Comment: I am using the Registration module.

Comment: @Shawn : please add that (crucial) info to your actual question (by edting it).

Answer (score 1):

You don't use contextual filter for this, you need to use relationship.

Make sure the Registration Views module is enabled.

In views under Advanced, RELATIONSHIP click add and select User: Registration

- Checkmark require this relationship.
- Checkmark your registration type name.

[image]